# stl library in dev cpp

Tags: c++, stl, dev-c++

I am learning stl features for the first time , so this code is from dietel and i wanted to implement in dev-c++ orwell 5.4 , but the code doesn't run , what is the problem . Are stl libraries not included in dev-cpp ?

And it is showing error - map doesnot name a type ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

typedef map< int , double , less< int > > Mid ; 
using namespace std ;

int main()
{
Mid pairs ;

pairs.insert( Mid::value_type( 15 , 2.7 ) ) ;
pairs.insert( Mid::value_type( 30 , 111.11 ) ) ;
pairs.insert( Mid::value_type( 5 , 1010.1 ) ) ;
pairs.insert( Mid::value_type( 10 , 22.22 ) ) ;
pairs.insert( Mid::value_type( 25 , 33.333 ) ) ;
pairs.insert( Mid::value_type( 5 , 77.54 ) ) ;
pairs.insert( Mid::value_type( 20 , 9.345 ) ) ;
pairs.insert( Mid::value_type( 15 , 99.3 ) ) ;

cout << "pairs contains:\nKey\tValue\n" ;

for( Mid::const_iterator iter = pairs.begin() ;
    iter != pairs.end() ; ++iter )
    cout << iter->first << '\t' << iter->second << '\n' ;

pairs[ 25 ] = 9999.99 ;
pairs[ 40 ] = 8765.43 ;
cout << endl ;
cout << "After subscript operations: " ;
cout << endl ;
for( Mid::const_iterator iter = pairs.begin() ;
    iter != pairs.end() ; ++iter )
    cout << iter->first << '\t' << iter->second << '\n' ;

cout << endl ;
return 0 ; 

}
```

Comment: Please include the _exact_ error you are getting, with line number information and its original text.

Comment: Since the answers make no mention of this, see [why is using namespace std considered bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: okay i understand why it shud not be used !

Comment: Please put in a little effort to formatting your post. For example, the English word "I" is always _capitalised_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

typedef map< int , double , less< int > > Mid ; 
using namespace std ;
```

In this code snippet, you are using `map` before telling that you are using tht e namespace `std`. Therefore, your compiler does not know where to look for `map` and tells you it never heard about it. Just write:

```
using namespace std ;
typedef map< int , double , less< int > > Mid ;
```

It should fix that problem.

Answer (score 1):

you are typedefing map before using namespace std;, that's why compiler can't see it